# What was the last version of Ruby where array range never returned nil?

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I have some Ruby code that no longer works because it assumes all out of bounds array range accesses will return the empty array instead of nil.

```
a = []
a[1..-1] == [] # code assumes this from ancient Ruby
a[1..-1] == nil # but gets this on newer Ruby >= 1.8
```

What was the last version of Ruby where array range was never nil?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using I'm using Ruby 2.0 and on the second line, b evaluates to nil.

Comment: You can fix this using the or operator, like so: `a[1..-1] || [] == []`. The or-clause executes if the return value is null. Also look up the use of `||=` (similar, but for assignment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's 1.2.x.

The oldest Ruby documentation I could find was was for [Ruby 1.2](http://web.archive.org/web/20000310211604/http://www.netlab.co.jp/ruby/man-1.2/Array.html). It says this about `Array#[]`:

> ```ruby
> self[start..end]
> ```
>
> Returns an array containing the objects from *start* to *end*, including both ends. if *end* is laeger[sic] than the length of the array, it will be rounded to the length. And if *start* is larger than *end*, this method returns empty array (`[]`).

So in 1.2, it always returns an array.

The next-oldest documentation I could find [was for Ruby 1.6](http://web.archive.org/web/20010125103200/http://dev.rubycentral.com/ref/ref_c_array.html). It says:

> *arr[anInteger] -> anObject or nil*
>   *arr[start, length] -> aSubArray or nil*
>   *arr[aRange] -> aSubArray or nil*
>
> Element Reference-Returns the element at index *anInteger*, or returns a subarray starting at index *start* and continuing for *length* elements, or returns a subarray specified by *aRange*. Negative indices count backward from the end of the array (-1 is the last element). **Returns `nil` if any indices are out of range.**

So that narrows it down a lot. Then I decided to go straight to the source. In Ruby 1.2, `Array#[]` is called [`ary_aref` in array.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_2_stable/array.c#L400-L430). If the argument is a range, it calls [`beg_len`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_2_stable/array.c#L367-L398) to get the beginning index and the length of the subsequence, and then calls [`ary_subseq`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_2_stable/array.c#L335-L364) with those arguments. Long story short, `ary_subseq` always returns an array, never `nil`.

Next I tried Ruby 1.3, where `Array#[]` [is now called `rb_ary_aref`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_3/array.c#L380-L417). Lo and behold, we see this ([406–414](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_3/array.c#L406-L414)):

```c
/* check if idx is Range */
switch (rb_range_beg_len(arg1, &beg, &len, RARRAY(ary)->len, 0)) {
  case Qfalse:
    break;
  case Qnil:
    return Qnil;
  default:
    return rb_ary_subary(ary, beg, len);
}
```

I think that speaks for itself: If the argument is out of range, return `nil`.

Since I'm terrible at C, I went and checked the Ruby 1.6 source (since we know from the documentation that it has the `nil` behavior) and found that [its implementation is the same](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_6_0/array.c#L417-L454).

I'm pretty confident, then, that Ruby 1.2.x is the last Ruby that returned an empty array, and 1.3.x is the first Ruby that returned `nil`.

Ruby 1.2, by the way, was released in 1998.

Comment: We need a way to describe this -- Code Paleontology?

Comment: @zetetic [Software](http://www.hpcf.upr.edu/~humberto/programmer-archaeologist.html) [archaeology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_archaeology). ;)